# Flutter App Hive Database Issue on Xiaomi Devices: Box not found error

Tags: flutter, google-play, flutter-hive

I have a Flutter app that uses the Hive database for local storage. The app works well on most devices; however, I've been encountering a "Box not found" error on Xiaomi devices specifically. The error message from Firebase Crashlytics is as follows:

```
"Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: HiveError: Box not found. Did you forget to call Hive.openBox()?. Error thrown Instance of 'ErrorDescription'."
```

I've already implemented a FutureBuilder to open all boxes and set initial values before accessing them, The issue still persists only on Xiaomi devices.

The apk was tested in a Xiaomi emulator using AWS Farm View, and in a Xiaomi device of a relative, but the google play app crashes on Xiome real device.

The error that Crashlytics talks about came from the home Screen when i check

`if (authProvider.login)`

login comes from:

`int get login => SettingsBox.getLogin();`

Here's the SettingsBox class:

```
class SettingsBox {
    static Box getBox() {
        String name = 'boxName';
        return Hive.box(name);
    }
    static Future<void> openBox() async {
        String name = 'boxName';
        /*ommiting opening box using encryptionCipher*/
        if (Hive.box(name).get('myLoginKey') == null) {
            await setLogin(false);
        }
    }
    static Future<void> setLogin(bool l) async {
        String keyLogin = 'myLoginKey';
        await getBox().put(keyLogin, l);
    }
    static bool getLogin() {
        String keyLogin = 'myLoginKey';
        return getBox().get(keyLogin);
    }
}
```

In the futureBuilder I run

```
await SettingsBox.openBox();
```

I'm unable to reproduce the issue on other devices and don't have direct access to a Xiaomi device for testing. I'm seeking suggestions on how to resolve this issue or gather more information to debug it further.

I tried check the error on Crashnalitics, I did not ask for storage permission because the database is on app folder.

Answer (score 0):

if the user do

1. Open the "Settings" app.
2. Tap "Apps"
3. Find and tap the app in the list of installed apps.
4. Tap "Storage"
5. Tap "Clear Data"
6. Tap "Clear all data"

The user can open the app without problem. Why is this necessary I don't know. If someone know the answer I would like to read. Probably is my last app using Hive database.